# How to disable LinkLabel TabStop?

Tags: winforms, linklabel

I place a LinkLabel on a form, by default it has `TabStop=true`. I change `TabStop` to `false` and close the form. Then open the form again - `TabStop` is `true`.

What happens and how do I disable `TabStop` for LinkLabel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set it to false in the code:

```
linkLabel1.TabStop = false;
```

I don't know why it doesn't respect the value set in the designer, it almost looks like it has a default value of True, but the designer thinks its default is false.

Comment: How crazy!  I was wondering why my program wouldn't respect "tabstop = false".  But I changed the program to force tabstop = false on load and the problem went away.

Comment: Don't be put off by the Visual Studio Code Completion not showing a TabStop property on your LinkLabel object.

Comment: Has to be a VS bug... You set the property to false in the designer and compile and it changes it back to true on your behalf. There is no excuse for that behaviour. Thanks John for the solution.

Comment: There're some buried properties for LinkLabel which seem to relate to the actual links but they're not individually accessible as far as I can tell:

Comment: There's a buried property for LinkLabel which may relate to the actual links but it's not individually accessible as far as I can tell:

    `TabStop (Label)`

(Comments acn only be edited for 5 minutes - thanks for telling me BEFOREHAND!)

Comment: @kad81 This seems to have been fixed at least in VA 2019. I've removed all my `myLinkLabel.TabStop = False` compensatory code and all is now well.